# How to filter a SQL query table by clicking on a link on Web application in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble with pushing the SQL query through to filter the table after the user clicks on a link in the sidebar. I am using the sample database Northwind to create this app. I have implemented a search function and sorting functions already. The user should be able to use any combination of sorting, searching, and filtering.

[This is the tutorial](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/243/MVC-5-with-EF-6-in-Visual-Basic-Sorting-Filtering-and-Paging) I followed for the majority of creating this application (minus the paging; I have kept everything on one page). I also removed the functionality for editing, adding, and deleting entries. I only want to be able to view the entries in the list view.

Below is my code - I have gotten to the point where I thought it would filter but nothing happens when the links on the side menu are pressed. The text is pushed to the end of the URL but that is it.

**Index.vbhtml**

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of WebApplication1_testdirectory.Customer)

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Customers"
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        * {
            list-style: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            background: #f5f6fa;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar {
            background: rgb(5, 68, 104);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 225px;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar .profile {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .wrapper .sidebar .profile img {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar .profile h3 {
            color: #ffffff;
            margin: 10px 0 5px;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar .profile p {
            color: rgb(206, 240, 253);
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 13px 30px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #10558d;
            color: rgb(241, 237, 237);
            font-size: 16px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a .icon {
            color: #dee4ec;
            width: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover,
        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active {
            color: #0c7db1;
            background: white;
            border-right: 2px solid rgb(5, 68, 104);
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover .icon,
        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active .icon {
            color: #0c7db1;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover:before,
        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active:before {
            display: block;
        }

        .wrapper .section {
            width: calc(100% - 225px);
            margin-left: 225px;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .wrapper .section .top_navbar {
            background: rgb(7, 105, 185);
            height: 50px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0 30px;
        }

        .wrapper .section .top_navbar .hamburger a {
            font-size: 28px;
            color: #f4fbff;
        }

        .wrapper .section .top_navbar .hamburger a:hover {
            color: #a2ecff;
        }

        body.active .wrapper .sidebar {
            left: -225px;
        }

        body.active .wrapper .section {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Northwind Employee Directory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Gridmvc.css" />
</head>
<body>


    <h2>Customers Directory</h2>

    <!--Top menu -->
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!--profile image & text-->
        <!--menu item-->
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="logo.jpg">
            <h3>Directory</h3>
            <p>Filter by Locations:</p>
        </div>


        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="active">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">All Locations</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Argentina">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Argentina</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Austria">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Austria</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Belgium">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Belgium</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Brazil">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-database"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Brazil</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Canada">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Canada</span>
                </a>
            </li>            
            <li>
                <a href="#France">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">France</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Germany">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Germany</span>
                </a>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <a href="#Portugal">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Portugal</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                      
            <li>
                <a href="#USA">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">USA</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Venezuela">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                    <span class="item">Venezuela</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    

    </div>

    @Using Html.BeginForm()
        @<p>
            Search by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")

            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    End Using

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.CompanyName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.TitleSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.City)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Country)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Phone)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Fax)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @For Each item In Model
            @<tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.ContactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.ContactTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.City)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Country)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Phone)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Fax)
                </td>
            </tr>
        Next
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CustomersController.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports WebApplication1_testdirectory
Imports PagedList


Namespace Controllers
    Public Class CustomersController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As New NorthwindEntities1

        ' GET: Customers
        Function Index(ByVal sortOrder As String, searchString As String, countryString As String) As ActionResult

            If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString)) Then
                countryString = countryString.Substring(1)
            End If

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder), "name_desc", String.Empty)
            ViewBag.TitleSortParm = If(sortOrder = "Title", "title_desc", "Title")
            ViewBag.CountryFilter = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString), String.Empty, countryString)


            Dim customers = From c In db.Customers Select c
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                              Or c.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())) And
                                              (c.Country.ToUpper().Contains(countryString.ToUpper()) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString)))
            End If



            Select Case sortOrder
                Case "name_desc"
                    customers = customers.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.ContactName)
                Case "title_desc"
                    customers = customers.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ContactTitle)
                Case Else
                    customers = customers.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ContactName)
            End Select


            Return View(customers.ToList())
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
            If (disposing) Then
                db.Dispose()
            End If
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to change in order to make the links in the sidebar filter. They needed to become `ActionLinks` in order to actually filter in the SQL table.
Changed from this:

```
<a href="#Argentina">
```

To this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Argentina", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Argentina"})
```

I also needed to fix the `If` statements in the controller to allow for both searching and filtering.
Changed from this:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                              Or c.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())) And
                                              (c.Country.ToUpper().Contains(countryString.ToUpper()) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString)))
            End If
```

To this:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                              Or c.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())) And
                                              (c.Country.ToUpper().Contains(countryString.ToUpper())))

            ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                                  Or c.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())))

            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.Country.ToUpper().Contains(countryString.ToUpper())))

            End If
```

**Here's the updated code:**

**Index.vbhtml:**

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of WebApplication1_testdirectory.Customer)

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Customers"
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        * {
            list-style: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            background: #f5f6fa;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar {
            background: rgb(5, 68, 104);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 225px;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 20px 0;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar .profile {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .wrapper .sidebar .profile img {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar .profile h3 {
            color: #ffffff;
            margin: 10px 0 5px;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar .profile p {
            color: rgb(206, 240, 253);
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 13px 30px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #10558d;
            color: rgb(241, 237, 237);
            font-size: 16px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a .icon {
            color: #dee4ec;
            width: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover,
        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active {
            color: #0c7db1;
            background: white;
            border-right: 2px solid rgb(5, 68, 104);
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover .icon,
        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active .icon {
            color: #0c7db1;
        }

        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover:before,
        .wrapper .sidebar ul li a.active:before {
            display: block;
        }

        .wrapper .section {
            width: calc(100% - 225px);
            margin-left: 225px;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .wrapper .section .top_navbar {
            background: rgb(7, 105, 185);
            height: 50px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0 30px;
        }

        .wrapper .section .top_navbar .hamburger a {
            font-size: 28px;
            color: #f4fbff;
        }

        .wrapper .section .top_navbar .hamburger a:hover {
            color: #a2ecff;
        }

        body.active .wrapper .sidebar {
            left: -225px;
        }

        body.active .wrapper .section {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Northwind Employee Directory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Gridmvc.css" />
</head>
<body>


    <h2>Customers Directory</h2>

    <!--Top menu -->
    <div class="sidebar">
        <!--profile image & text-->
        <!--menu item-->
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="logo.jpg">
            <h3>Directory</h3>
            <p>Filter by Locations:</p>
        </div>


        <ul>
            <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("All Locations", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = ""})
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                    <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Argentina", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Argentina"})
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></span>
                    <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Austria", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Austria"})
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i></span>
                    <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Belgium", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Belgium"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Brazil", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Brazil"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-database"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
                
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Canada", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Canada"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
                     
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("France", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "France"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Germany", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Germany"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
            </li>           
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Portugal", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Portugal"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
                      
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("USA", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "USA"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>     
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Venezuela", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, .countryString = "Venezuela"})
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>
                <span class="item"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    

    </div>

    @Using Html.BeginForm()
        @<p>
            Search by name or title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")

            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    End Using



    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.CompanyName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.TitleSortParm, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter})
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.City)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Country)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Phone)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Fax)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @For Each item In Model
            @<tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.ContactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.ContactTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.City)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Country)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Phone)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Fax)
                </td>
            </tr>
        Next
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CustomersController.vb:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports WebApplication1_testdirectory
Imports PagedList


Namespace Controllers
    Public Class CustomersController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As New NorthwindEntities1

        ' GET: Customers
        Function Index(ByVal sortOrder As String, searchString As String, countryString As String) As ActionResult

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder), "name_desc", String.Empty)
            ViewBag.TitleSortParm = If(sortOrder = "Title", "title_desc", "Title")
            ViewBag.CountryFilter = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString), String.Empty, countryString)


            Dim customers = From c In db.Customers Select c
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                              Or c.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())) And
                                              (c.Country.ToUpper().Contains(countryString.ToUpper())))

            ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                                  Or c.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())))

            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryString) Then
                customers = customers.Where(Function(c) (c.Country.ToUpper().Contains(countryString.ToUpper())))

            End If


            Select Case sortOrder
                Case "name_desc"
                    customers = customers.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.ContactName)
                Case "title_desc"
                    customers = customers.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ContactTitle)
                Case Else
                    customers = customers.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ContactName)
            End Select


            Return View(customers.ToList())
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
            If (disposing) Then
                db.Dispose()
            End If
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

I used this site (https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/html-actionlink-complete-example-aspnet-mvc5.php) to help with the `ActionLinks`.